# How to pipe xargs output to a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop

I'm using HDFS Find tool to archive older than a certain amount of time into another directory. I'll later compress this directory. Note that I want to maintain the directory structure and hence I have to do a mkdir and move rather than a simple move.

Here's how the command goes inside my bash script:

```
hadoop jar $jar_location $find_tool -find hdfs://${inputDirs[$x]} -mtime +$days -type f | cut -c 20- | xargs -I % hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /archiveData/tmp/$DATE`dirname %` && hdfs dfs -mv % /archiveData/tmp/$DATE`dirname %`
```

I'm trying to find files older than a certain amount of time from the set of folders given in *inputDirs*. I get a file, say:

```
/user/abc/file1.txt
```

I'm then passing the above as input to the xargs. I then want to create a directory `/archiveData/tmp/$DATE/user/abc` and then move the `file1.txt` under it.

The move fails with the below error:

> mv: `%': No such file or directory

And it creates a directory as `/archiveData/tmp/$DATE.` instead of `/archiveData/tmp/$DATE/user/abc`

Comment: One problem is that `dirname %` gets evaluated *before* being passed as argument to xargs. Another problem seems to be about "&&" - the part after && is interpreted as an independent command, not as argument to xargs - so is not seen by xargs either. I think you'll be better off with a `while read line; do ... done` cycle instead of xargs in that case.

Comment: `xargs` starts an external program; it does not run an arbitrary shell command, so the `&&` signals the end of the `xargs` command and the beginning of a new shell command.